# Im new to php, how can I use links to change what loads on a page?

Tags: php, get

What I was looking for before was a way to dynamically create  links for the same directory but have different URL variables, that way the same page works from the variables provided to load images from a folder. Below was my example code for loading all of the images inside the directory.

```
$dir = "./Ch.001/";

$a = glob($dir."*png");

foreach($a as $image){
    echo "<img src='". $image ."'>";
}

?>
```

At the time I wasn't sure what to research to achieve what I wanted but thanks to an answer and some more experience in PHP, my answer to what I was looking for above would have been $_GET variables and urlencode()/htmlspecialchars().

Now I would use a database to store all of the information I wanted to display, so when the series is created from a form I would store the title, description, etc, and then calculate how many rows are in the database, and then make that number + 1 the file name, and maybe add a prefix so it isn't just numbers.

Comment: You already answer your question, just make a lot o vars or make an array of paths ( highly recommended ) to load a path that you want. So, when you click to load the "chapter 2" you load a path accordingly to your array. Understand?

Comment: that makes alot more sense ill try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming 001 is `001` to `n` etc.

Use a simple [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) parameter, check or cast to int, 0 pad it and then show your links with +1 for next.

```
<?php
$chapter = str_pad((int) ($_GET['chapter'] ?? '001'), 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

//
$dir = "./Ch.$chapter/";

//
$images = glob($dir."*png");

if (empty($images)) {
    echo '<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>';
} else {
    foreach($images as $image){
        echo "<img src='". $image ."'>";
    }

    echo 'Chapter: '.$chapter.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Goto <a href="?chapter='.($chapter+1).'">Chapter</a>';
}
```

Comment: So i understand what its trying to do from the $dir variable onwards, but what is being done in the $chapter variable? if you dont mind explaining it to me, also you presume 001 to n?

Comment: its grabbing $_GET var, casting to int then 0 padding left as said. integers in any lang remove the leading 0's without padding it wont find the folder. example: https://3v4l.org/33isE